# MVP pattern user controls, presenter question

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvp

I am going to start a website, where We want to implement MVP pattern. 
One of our page is broken into small user controls so they are used to 
edit or display information. But later on we save the whole information
from the main page. Also during the load time, the information is sent 
from the main page to the controls. If I design a separate Presenter 
for each user control and write logic in that to capture information, there will be many calls to database, whereas if i write that logic in the main presenter and pass data to the user controls, it will just one call. how should it be designed.

Let me explain it.

I have a webform where I capture details like Car make, model, milage, client detail
like name, contact phone number etc. all the controls can be put into one form,
but instead, I created separate controls for each information, like one control for car information, other for customer information. But later on, I want save the whole information from the main page not from the controls. So how will i achieve it using MVP pattern. Should I create separate presenter for each control, then how will I pass information from a user control to the webform, when hit the save button.

Your help will be appritiated.

Regards
Parminder

Comment: just out of curiosity, are there any inherent advantages you see with MVP  than using MVC ?

Comment: Actually we are not yet ready for MVC, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [Unit of Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) design pattern for saving information, where each child control will add queries to save and your main control will SubmitChanges.